# Spring - Is it good to register request scoped bean at every request though code?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring Web application, I have to use specific value from request object in another spring classes within application. Value is request specific value.

In the following example, is it good way to register value coming from **Request Body** every time and use `@Autowired` with `@RequestScope` annotation to use value in another spring(e.g. @Service) classes? Is it good to register `RequestScopedType` bean value for each request through `BeanFactory`?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class VehicleServiceController {

  @Autowired 
  private BeanFactory beanFactory;
  @Autowired 
  private ServiceClass serviceClass;

  @PostMapping(path = "/postDetails", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public OutputPayload postDetails(
        @RequestBody InputPayload inboundPayload) throws Exception {
    beanFactory.getBean(RequestScopedType.class).setValue(inboundPayload.getType());
    return serviceClass.methodToCall();
  }
}
```

Will there be any impact on performance as load is very huge? Is there any another way to inject/get `RequestBody` object value(`inboundPayload.getType()`)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do `beanFactory.getBean(RequestScopedType.class)`. You can just simply autowire it `@Autowired RequestScopedType requestScopedType`.

Just don't forget to change the scope of the bean as Request.

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RequestScopedType {
```

But this begs another question, why over complicate things, why can't you pass `inboundPayload.getType()` to the `serviceClass.methodToCall();` ?

What is stopping you from using it this way `return serviceClass.methodToCall(inboundPayload.getType());`